# How to use three channel images in FeedForward Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, feed-forward

As **FeedForward Neural Networks** (Not CNN) has only one Layer of Data i.e. It has the ability to process only GrayScale images. How do we make it process Color (RGB) **3-Channel images**?

Comment: What do you mean one layer of data? What you say that it can only process grayscale images is completely false.

Comment: In a grayscale image, you have a two dimension tensor.
In rgb, you have three dimension tensor with h=h, w=w, d=3

Comment: So? You need to flatten it in both cases.

Comment: How can you use 3 channel images with FeedForward NN?

Comment: flattening is used in CNN, I'm using feedforward architecture.

Comment: Flattening can be done with data.flatten(), if data is a numpy array, it has literally nothing to do with CNNs, it can be used with MLPs. Note that a CNN is a feedforward architecture.

Comment: I don't get your flatten concept

Comment: It just linearizes the data so it has a 1D representation, the same as the keras layer Flatten, or by using reshape with the appropriate parameters ( like data.reshape((-1, np.prod(data.shape[1:]))) )

Comment: can you explain it with the concept of Tensors, I'm from PyTorch side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following methods.

1. Add pixel-wise values of RGB channels and give it as 1-channel image
   to your Feedforward Neural Network.
2. Add pixel-wise values of RGB
   channel, divide pixel values by 3 and give it as grey-scale image to
   your Feedforward Neural Network.
3. Perpend 3 Linear layers to your
   model, apply a non-linear function, add 3 Layers results Neuron wise
   and then give it your as input to your Feedforward Neural Network.